# Is there a direct way to copy files from ServerA to ServerB when only one of them requires impersonation?

Tags: vb.net, impersonation

I am trying to copy files from `Server A` to `Server B`.

So basically, it's fast and easy, `File.Copy`.

```
File.Copy("\\ServerA\c$\CopyImageTest\Server61.txt", "\\ServerB\c$\CopyImageTest\Server61.txt")  
File.Copy("\\ServerB\c$\CopyImageTest\Server182.txt", "\\ServerA\c$\CopyImageTest\Server182.txt")
```

Since `Server A` requires login to use, it's obvious that I got this error:

> System.IO.IOException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

I've looked around and found that I should use `Impersonation` in order to access that server and copy the files. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16307879/6783663) which is in `C#` and converted it to `VB.NET`.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
Module Module1

    <PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
    Sub Main()
        Try
           'Some declarations omitted for clearance.
            Const LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT As Integer = 0
            Const LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE As Integer = 2
            Const LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS As Integer = 9

            Try
                Dim bImpersonated As Boolean = LogonUser(sUsername, sDomain, sPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, pExistingTokenHandle)

                If (Not bImpersonated) Then
                    Dim nErrorCode As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                    Return
                End If

                Dim bRetVal As Boolean = DuplicateToken(pExistingTokenHandle, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, pDuplicateTokenHandle)

                If (Not bRetVal) Then
                    Dim nErrorCode As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                    CloseHandle(pExistingTokenHandle)
                    Return
                Else
                    Dim newId As WindowsIdentity = New WindowsIdentity(pDuplicateTokenHandle)
                    Dim impersonateduser As WindowsImpersonationContext = newId.Impersonate()

                    'Shouldn't I be copying now?
                    File.Copy("\\ServerA\c$\CopyImageTest\Server61.txt", "\\ServerB\c$\CopyImageTest\Server61.txt")  
                    File.Copy("\\ServerB\c$\CopyImageTest\Server182.txt", "\\ServerA\c$\CopyImageTest\Server182.txt")

                    sResult = sResult & "After impersonation: " & WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name & Environment.NewLine
                    impersonateduser.Undo()
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                'Omitted
            Finally
                If (Not pExistingTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero) Then
                    CloseHandle(pExistingTokenHandle)
                End If

                If (Not pDuplicateTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero) Then
                    CloseHandle(pDuplicateTokenHandle)
                End If
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Omitted
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' DLL Imports and Enum Omitted.
End Module
```

Some code to output the results has been omitted, but here's the results from the console:

```
User was able to login. (This is used after LogonUser()) (Previously it was throwing an error (1326) Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password)
Before impersonation: User-PC\User (Result of WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; Before Impersonate())
After impersonation: User-PC\User (Result of WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; After Impersonate())

System.IO.IOException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

What's confusing is that the name before and after impersonation is the same as my local PC. However the login is working. (*I am positive about that because, as stated, it was failing previously.*)

Secondly, the file still doesn't get copied with same error as before:

```
Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

Is this how actually `Impersonation` should be working, or am I missing something obvious?

After digging a bit more, I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958143/6783663) and I used the same exact code from the answer, but with no luck at all.

Some information about the `Server A` that I am trying to access and copy the files from:

- I can connect through remote desktop connecting using the same username/password.
- I can open the file explorer from my own PC using the server IP address as shown in the code: `\\ServerA\c$\CopyImageTest`.
- Both my PC and the server are on the same network, but different domains.

### Update:

@Esko's comment guided me to make two or three tests.

Here's the scenario:

- With Impersonation I tried this code:

  ```
  File.Copy("\\ServerA\c$\CopyImageTest\Server61.txt", "C:\CopyImageTest\Server61.txt")
  File.Copy("C:\CopyImageTest\Server182.txt", "\\ServerA\c$\CopyImageTest\Server182.txt")
  ```

  Which means that I only copied the files from `ServerA` to local and vice versa.
  **Result: Passed**.
- With Impersonation

  ```
  File.Copy("C:\CopyImageTest\Server61.txt", "\\ServerB\c$\CopyImageTest\Server61.txt")
  File.Copy("\\ServerB\c$\CopyImageTest\Server182.txt", "C:\CopyImageTest\Server182.txt")
  ```

  Which means I tried to copy from `ServerB` to local and vice verca
  **Result: Failed**
- Without impersonation

  ```
  File.Copy("C:\CopyImageTest\Server61.txt", "\\ServerB\c$\CopyImageTest\Server61.txt")
  File.Copy("\\ServerB\c$\CopyImageTest\Server182.txt", "C:\CopyImageTest\Server182.txt")
  ```

  Copying from and to `ServerB`
  **Result: Passed**

So at the end, I think the problem is that when Impersonating the user to access `ServerA` it fails to access `ServerB`, knowing that `ServerB` doesn't require `username` `password` when trying to access it from my PC. *Maybe because my PC and `ServerB` uses same domain on same network but `ServerA` uses another domain on same network*?

**Is there any workaround to access both servers with a single impersonation**?

**Note**: I am aware of being able to copy files from `ServerA` to local then undo impersonation and copy to `ServerB`, I am just looking for a more straight way.

Comment: Is this a Asp.Net-application or a windows-application? I think the reason why it's not working is that delegation of credentials is not enabled on server A. Server A is unable to transfer credentials to third party (server B) if delegation is not enabled for the server in Active Directory.

Comment: Currently it's just a proof of concept console application. Later on it will be implemented in a windows form application. So to answer your question, it's a windows-application.

Comment: You don't need any impersonation of you simply run the console application with the credentials that you want to use.

Comment: @Esko Your comment made me think of something else and I did three tests. Updating the question to show what I found out.